# android Как узнать, что приложения удаляют?

Tags: android

android Как узнать, что приложения удаляют? и перед удалением выполнить действия по очистке данных

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cоздайте класс, унаследуйте его от  BroadcastReceiver, и в манифесте объявите его таким образом:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.UninstallApplicationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Далее перекройте onReceive, в котором опишите Вашу логику при удалении приложения

```
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getDataString().equals("package:your.package.name")) {
      //methods
   }
 }
```

Comment: А можно как-то узнать что удаляют именно то приложение, на котором висит данный ресивер?

Comment: @pavel обновил ответ

Comment: Вы видимо меня не поняли, я имел ввиду вот эту фразу в документации 'The package that is being removed does not receive this Intent.' Каким-то образом её можно обойти, или использовать что-то другое для достижения аналогичного результата.

Comment: Есть вариант создать ещё одно маленькое приложение, задачей которого будет зачистка и самоудаление. Но да, это костыль.